# Adding flow definiton to typescript library

Tags: flowtype

I have written a library called [redux-async-action-reducer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-async-action-reducer). I have written it in typescript. I want to add flow definition to it.

Is there any way I can keep it along with my library rather than creating a separate and putting it in [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed)?

Something like d.ts for flow defintion files?

Comment: Why would you add flow, when you are already using typescript?

Comment: So that consumers of the library who are using Flow can also get type checking

Comment: OP might find https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1996#issuecomment-230919868 interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You could ship your library with a `.js.flow` file alongside your package entry point. In your case (since your package entry point is `dist/index.js` you would create a file at `dist/index.js.flow`.

Flow will then treat this like a normal source file. You'll have to remember to put `// @flow` at the top. You can either write functions and classes with stubbed out implementations, or use `declare` (e.g. `declare export function foo(x: string): string;`, similar for class).

Note that this will actually be different than a library definition file -- Flow will treat it like source code.

Flow-typed is the preferred way to distribute libdefs. Using `.js.flow` files can lead to issues when Flow makes breaking changes between versions. However, since you will be distributing a hand-curated interface, rather than shipping your entire library source as `.js.flow` files, that issue will be mitigated.